# How to get the output of a system command as a returned value from a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code shown below is intended to output the present working directory to the console. Instead it outputs, "undefined". For purposes of this learning experience, it is important that I obtain the desired result as the returned value of the system function. Any ideas on how I can make this work?

```
#!/usr/bin/node
var child_process = require('child_process');
function system(cmd) {
  child_process.exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  return stdout;
})};
console.log(system('pwd'));
```

Comment: *"For purposes of this learning experience, it is important that I obtain the desired result as the returned value of the system function."* That's impossible. `child_process.exec` is an asynchronous process (that's why you have to pass a callback to it). For information why you get `undefined` (and how to solve that), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 4):

exec is executed asynchronously. Pass a callback to your function and you're set.

```
#!/usr/bin/node
var child_process = require('child_process');

function system(cmd, callback) {
  child_process.exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
     //You should handle error or pass it to the callback
     callback(stdout); 
  });
}

system('pwd', function(output){ 
  console.log(output); 
});
```

And here's how you would do it synchronously,  which I believe is what you were looking for.

```
function systemSync(cmd) {
  return child_process.execSync(cmd).toString();
}

console.log(systemSync("pwd"));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Works great.  Actually I was looking for both the sync and the async way for doing it as I am having a bit of trouble getting my head wrapped around callbacks.  So, your answer was most helpful.  Thanks.